# Reference data from views in breeze

Tags: breeze

We have a table (AttendanceType) in our database which have many fields with multiple options. this multiple options are defined in single table. So, instead of creating separate Option table for each option we have single table (Option_Data) with key to identify each option type (Record).

Example : AttendanceType table has following fields

- ID
- Description
- Category (Payroll / Accrual)
- Type  (Hours / Days)
- Mode (Work hours / Overtime / ExtraHours)
- Operation (Add / Minus)

These fields have options (data as shown above in brackets) which comes from Option_data table. We have created separate views from this Option_data table example: vwOption_Attendance_Mode, vwOption_Attendance_Operation etc.

Now, how we can link this view in breeze so the reference data come automatically.

We are using EF6, SqlServer, Asp.Net WebApi. When the table relationship is defined in SQL Server Breeze works perfectly and manages the relational data. In this case we cannot define relationship in SQL Server between Table and Views.

How we can code it so Breeze can manage the relational / reference data for us? If you require further clarification please let me know.

Edit @ Jay Traband : Let say a single table (ie: AttendanceType) has fields which get reference/lookup data for its field from Views. How in breeze we can relate them (table with views), as in SQL Server we cannot.
My reference points is when Tables are related breeze does excellent job. I want to achieve same with table and views.

Comment: A little more detail please. Still not sure I understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Breeze gets its metadata (including the relationships between entities) from EF.  You'll need to tell EF about the relationship between the tables and views, even if there is no such relationship defined in SQL Server.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184617/how-to-create-a-relationship-between-table-and-view-in-the-entity-framework) provides some clues, and [this blog post](http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2012/01/18/manually-creating-referential-constraints-in-entity-framework-4/) gives some related information about creating relationships in the designer.

Comment: My requirement is almost same as mentioned in the blog post, only that the reference/lookup field is not primary key in the table and the relationship is between table and the views, and need to use Breeze :)